# AngularJS ng-view Layout manage

Tags: angularjs

Hi I am working on a project using angularjs. 
My roting logic is

```
.state( "authenticate", {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl : "views/login.html", 
        controller  : "LoginCtrl",
        data : {
            requireLogin : false
        }
    })
    .state( "beats", {
        url: '/beats',
        templateUrl : "views/beats.html", 
        controller  : "BeatsCtrl",
        data : {
            requireLogin : true
        }
    })

.state( "outlets", {
        url: '/outlets',
        templateUrl : "views/beats.html", 
        controller  : "BeatsCtrl",
        data : {
            requireLogin : true
        }
    })
```

I have `ng-view` in `index.html` that includes `login.html` first (url '/'). after login in each state I want to include a `navbar` in each template using `ng-include`.

currently I am writing in each page this line

```
<div ng-include=" 'templates/navbar.html' "></div>
```

but I want to include only once and each view should be render below it. But the problem is this navbar template itself getting render in ng-view.
and as far as I know we can not have multiple ng-view in one app.

can anyone please tell me what should be the best approach of doing this.

Answer (score 3):

You could potentially have this nav bar included in the index.html itself, but hide it using ng-if or ng-show till the user is logged in. Once the user is logged in you could have a flag that evaluates to true and this nav bar can appear on every subsequent page.

in index.html

```
<div id="navbar" ng-if="isUserLoggedIn">
    // nav bar code
</div>
```

And this 'isUserLoggedIn' will be set to true by your LoginCtrl on the scope.